# How to change color from CSS?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have node "Text" and i need change color from CSS. I am trying

```
-fx-text-fill: black;
```

but it doesn`t work. Can anyone help?
I think, that there is another property for "Text" node, but i cant find it.

Comment: Can you show a little bit more code? Like, if are you adding this directly to your node in Java, using `setStyle(...)` show the code, or  if are you skinning it using a custom CSS file, show the code and the complete CSS fragment in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-fx-fill use `linear-gradient` try this...

```
txt.setStyle(" -fx-font: 100px Tahoma;
-fx-fill: linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 100% 200%, repeat, red 0%, red 50%)");
```